# CodeIgniter and Secrets/API Keys

Tags: git, codeigniter, github, api-key

So im writing code and pushing it to github and pushing it to github etc etc....

Problem is when I do that I am also pushing things like Facebook API keys and config.php encryption keys - anyone know how to push code without doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't include them in your code and use environment variables:

```
$my_very_secret_key = getenv("MY_VERY_SECRET_KEY");
```

You'll define this key wherever your webserver will allow you to. For instance with nginx:

```
env MY_VERY_SECRET_KEY='OhThatsAVerySecretKey'
```

This procedure is recommended by Heroku to [store s3 credentials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), it's imho the best way to go.

If you're using a package manager(such as composer), you can install the [Dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) package, which allows you to use a `.env` file in the root of your project. Make sure this file isn't readable from the web though, otherwise your security keys will be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Store your keys in an external file configuration file that you exclude with a project-level *.gitignore*. If you've already committed your keys, you should remove them from the repository with git-filter-branch(1).

#### See Also

- https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History
- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch